# glmfit in MATLAB vs glm in R.. getting different answers

Tags: r, matlab, linear-regression, glm

```
% A set of car weights\
weight = [0.17. 0.27, 0.44, 0.56, 0.65, 0.79, 0.98, 1.25, 1.56, 2.1, 2.42, 3.02, 3.6, 4.02]';

% The number of cars tested at each weight\
tested = [45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45]';

% The number of cars failing the test at each weight\
failed = [0 0 0 0 4 12 24 37 41 44 45 45 45 45]';
```

Following are my setup:

IN MATLAB:

```
X = [tested failed]
y = log(weight)
[beta, std] = glmfit(y, X, 'binomial', 'link', 'probit');
```

The Result: `beta = [-0.6399, 3.2251]`

IN Rstudio:

```
y <- log(weight) 
X <- cbind (tested, failed) 
model <-glm(X~y, family=binomial(link="probit"))
```

The Result: `summary(model) = [-0.905, 0.753]`

The results are obviously different and for the life of me I can't seem to figure out why. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Should not, for your model, the response variable be 0 or 1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you misread the doc:

**Matlab:**

```
% A set of car weights
x = [0.17, 0.27, 0.44, 0.56, 0.65, 0.79, 0.98, 1.25, 1.56, 2.1, 2.42, 3.02, 3.6, 4.02]';
% The number of cars tested at each weight
n = [45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45 45]';
% The number of cars failing the test at each weight
y = [0 0 0 0 4 12 24 37 41 44 45 45 45 45]';

x = log(x);
[beta, std] = glmfit(x,[y, n], 'binomial', 'link', 'probit')

% beta = [0.0574 3.2919]
% With glmfit(predictor,[passed tested]... 
% not  glmfit(predictor,[tested passed]...
% I'm even surprised that matlab output something else than an error.
```

**R:**

```
# A set of car weights
x <- c(0.17, 0.27, 0.44, 0.56, 0.65, 0.79, 0.98, 1.25, 1.56, 2.1, 2.42, 3.02, 3.6, 4.02);
# The number of cars tested at each weight
n <- c(45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45);
# The number of cars failing the test at each weight
y <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 12, 24, 37, 41, 44, 45, 45, 45, 45);

model <-glm(y/n~log(x), family=binomial(link="probit"),weights=n)

summary(model)

#Coefficients:
#            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#(Intercept)  0.05736    0.09488   0.605    0.545    
#log(x)       3.29185    0.28049  11.736   <2e-16 ***
```

Now the model is pretty accurate:

[image]

Comment: There are a couple of issues here: your R specification should be `glm(formula = y/n ~ log(x), family = binomial(link = "probit"),  weights = n)` OR `glm(formula = cbind(y, n - y) ~ log(x), family = binomial(link = "probit"))`

Comment: @BenBolker yups indeed, I've edited my answer. Thanks

Comment: @obchardon, thanks a ton guys, this helps!